# JavaScript One line problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works:

```
$('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? alert('Bla') : null;
```

but this codes don't:

```
$('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? function(){alert('Bla'); return false; } : null;

$('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? alert('Bla');return false; : null;

$('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? return false : null;
```

i need "alert" after "return false"

How can I do that ?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Why does it have to be one line - stick it an if() {  } and it's no longer an issue...

Comment: You can't so anything after a return statement, kind of the point.

Comment: You should provide a more complete example. And fact is that you just cannot execute code in a function **after** you returned from the function. You have to change the structure of your code. If you explain *what* you want to do, we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do like this:

`$('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? (function(){alert('Bla'); return false; })() : null;`

`function(){alert('Bla'); return false; }` is just declaration of the function. Brackets will execute it: **(declaration of function...)()**

**EDIT:** 
do you mean that you need to do like this?:

`function bla(){ return  ($('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? (function(){alert('Bla'); return false; })() : (function(){return null;})() ); }`

**explanation:** 
the function will return whatever ***( condition ? val1 : val2 )*** expression will return... in this case ***val1*** and ***val2*** are both functions and they are returning some values(val1 -> false; val2 -> null;) and that value is returned by main(bla) function.

Comment: Yes your code is work but function bla(){ $('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? (function(){alert('Bla'); return false; })() : null;
Alert('Not Return') } how to make bla function return, thank you...

Answer (score 2):

don't know exactly what you're trying to do (and you missed to show the error-message to us - but why don't you simply use a "normal" if-statement like this (which has no effect on performace but is much more readable (my opinion) and easier to change (if you have to, in the future)):

```
if($('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0"){
  // do something
}else{
  // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var test = $('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? false : null;
if (test === false) {
    alert('Bla');
    return false;
}
```

You can't return from within a ?: construct.  Even if you could it would be a very confusing piece of code to read.  Code is read far more often than it is written.

Better still if you're prepared to drop the ?: construct entirely use the answer from @oezi.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not practical:

```
$('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? alert('Bla');return false; : null;
```

You can simply check its value like this:

```
alert($('[id$=lbl]').val());
```

To go real-world/practical, you should actually be doing:

```
var myvalue = $('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? when true : when false;
```

**Example:**

```
var myvalue = $('[id$=lbl]').val() == "0" ? '' : $('[id$=lbl]').val();
```

Now `myvalue` will either be empty when it contains `0` or will have the value of the field specified. You can change off course according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id$=lbl]').val() === 0
```